# javascript goodchars function stopped working

Tags: javascript

I had this function working fine, and all of a sudden I see it's not working. I isolated it, and still I don't manage to see what's wrong with it.
I created a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/w82AW/

```
function getkey(e){
        if(window.event)
            return window.event.keyCode;
        else if(e)
            return e.which;
        else
            return null;
    }

    function goodchars(e, goods){
        console.log('e:'+e+', goods:'+goods);
        var key, keychar;
        key=getkey(e);
        console.log('e:'+e+', key:'+key);
        if(key==null) return true;
        keychar=String.fromCharCode(key);
        keychar=keychar.toLowerCase();
        goods=goods.toLowerCase();
        if(goods.indexOf(keychar)!=-1)
        return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? In any case, if you change your fiddle from `onload` to `no wrap - in head` it eliminates the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen for ***keypress***, not *keyup*. By the time *keyup* happens, it's too late to prevent the event. You also need to actually pass the `event` into the function, not the *String* `"theNumber"`

You can clean up your code a little, too

```js
function validKey(e, whitelist) {
    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    whitelist = whitelist.toLowerCase();
    if (whitelist.indexOf(char) !== -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="theNumber" name="theNumber" size="3"
       onkeypress="return validKey(event || window.event, '0123456789');"
/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpd5a/) (notice that the fiddle is set to *No wrap - in <head>*)

Comment: For IE<=8 support, use `e.which || e.keyCode || 0`

Comment: Thanks Paul, you were right, it was the "onkeypress", I totally forgot I changed it. http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/w82AW/3/ By the way, where do I put the e.which || e.keyCode || 0

Comment: @Sebastian in the code I wrote, instead of simply `e.which`

Answer (score 0):

Change you fiddle to wrap your script in head, instead of unload. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w82AW/1/)

```
function getkey(e){
    if(window.event)
        return window.event.keyCode;
    else if(e)
        return e.which;
    else
        return null;
}

function goodchars(e, goods){
    console.log('e:'+e+', goods:'+goods);
    var key, keychar;
    key=getkey(e);
    console.log('e:'+e+', key:'+key);
    if(key==null) return true;
    keychar=String.fromCharCode(key);
    keychar=keychar.toLowerCase();
    goods=goods.toLowerCase();
    if(goods.indexOf(keychar)!=-1)
    return true;
    return false;
}
```